# Java. Hibernate. foreign key

Tags: java, hibernate

Есть 2 таблицы в БД.

```
1)users (id, name, login, password)
2)MessageSystem(id, from_id, to_id .....)
```

Поля `from_id, to_id` являются внешними ключами и ссылаются на `id` у `users`.

Вот собственно, что он мне пишет:

```
org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Use of @OneToMany or @ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class: DataBaseService.dataSets.UsersDataSet.messageDataSet[DataBaseService.dataSets.MessageDataSet]
```

Код файла UsersDataSet.java

```
    import javax.persistence.*;
    import java.io.Serializable;
    import java.util.HashSet;
    import java.util.Set;

    @Entity
    @Table(name = "users")
    public class UsersDataSet implements Serializable {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = -8706689714326132798L;

        @Id
        @Column(name = "id")
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private long id;

        @Column(name = "name", updatable = false, unique = true)
        private String name;

        @Column(name = "login", updatable = false, unique = true)
        private String login;

        @Column(name = "password", updatable = false)
        private String password;

        @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "fromId")
        private Set<MessageDataSet> sendMessage = new HashSet<MessageDataSet>(0);

        @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "toId")
        private Set<MessageDataSet> receivedMessage = new HashSet<MessageDataSet>(0);


//setters getters....
```

Код файла MessageDataSet.java

```
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;

@Entity
@Table(name = "messagesystem")
public class MessageDataSet implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id_msg")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id_msg;

    @Column(name = "body_msg")
    private String body_msg;

    @Column(name = "date_msg")
    private String date_msg;

    @Column(name = "sender_del")
    private boolean sender_del;

    @Column(name = "receiver_del")
    private boolean receiver_del;

    @Column(name = "receiver_view")
    private boolean receiver_view;


    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "from_id")
    private UsersDataSet fromId;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "to_id")
    private UsersDataSet toId;
    //setters getters...
```

Comment: `mappedBy = "users"` в аннотации к `UsersDataSet.messageDataSet` это что по Вашему? А на самом деле это должно быть имя поля прямой  стороны отношения `OneToMany`, т.е. `ManyToOne`. В Вашем случае очевидно это должно быть `MessageDataSet.fromId` т.е. `mappedBy = "fromId"` (toId тоже хороший кандидат, Вам должно быть виднее)

Comment: @Sergey Спасибо попробую, а у меня же 2 ключа, а поле там одно, как мне быть не подскажите?

Comment: Ну Вы сами смотрите чем является UsersDataSet.messageDataSet, множеством отправленных мессаг или принятых, с соответствующим полем и связывайте. Если надо и то и другой, то сделайте допустим UsersDataSet.messagesFromUser и UsersDataSet.messagesToUser. один связать с fromId, другой c toId

Comment: Кстати странно называть класс сущности EntityDataSet, ведь экземпляр представляет собой отдельную сущность, а не набор данных. Хотя я тоже редко переименовываю то, что нагенерит какой-нибудь генератор кода.

Comment: @Sergey Внёс ваши правки, не помогло(

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4956855/hibernate-problem-use-of-onetomany-or-manytomany-targeting-an-unmapped-clas

Comment: У вас одна из сущностей не упомянута в hibernate.cfg.xml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Скорее всего одна из сущностей просто не упомянута в hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        ...
        <mapping class="com.example.domain.User"/>
        <mapping class="com.example.domain.Message"/>
    </session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>
```

Кроме того, у вас очень много лишнего в классах сущностей и вам стоит поработать над стилем:

1. Имя класса сущности принято писать в единственном числе - User, Message.
2. Имена переменных в Java принято писать в lowerCamelCase - не body_msg, а bodyMsg.
3. Анотации Hibernate следуют принципу configuration by exception. То есть бóльшую часть анотаций надо писать только тогда, когда не устраивает поведение по умолчанию.
4. В частности поля типа OneToMany ленивые по умолчанию.
5. Зачем вам сериализация? Вы используете её где-то ещё?
6. Зачем вы присваиваете пустой HashSet полям, значения которых всё равно будут внедряться?

Вполне достаточно будет этого:

```
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false, updatable = false, unique = true)
    private String login;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String password;

    @Column
    private String name;

    @OneToMany
    @OrderBy("sent")
    private Set<Message> sentMessages;

    @OneToMany
    @OrderBy("sent")
    private Set<Message> receivedMessages;

    public User() {}

    public User(String login, String password) {
        setLogin(login);
        setPassword(password);
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getLogin() {
        return login;
    }

    public void setLogin(String login) {
        this.login = login;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return getLogin();
    }
}


@Entity
public class Message {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    Long id;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date sent;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    String text;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private User from;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private User to;

    public Message() {}

    public Message(User from, User to, String text) {
        this.from = from;
        this.to = to;
        this.text = text;
        this.sent = new Date();
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    // ... Остальные геттеры и сеттеры

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Message from " + from + " to " + to + ": " + getText();
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо вам за советы и ответ! Оказывается у меня вообще не было файла hibernate.cfg.xml, а в место этого конфигурация бралась из кода